# What is the difference between to "draw" and to "describe"

Tags: geometry, terminology

Reading the famous book "The Elements of Euclid". And I found this:

> Draw [a dotted line] (post. I.), describe [a triangle], and produce [another line].

In here, the word "Draw" and the word "Describe" are both used.

As you know, to describe means to trace or mark. While to draw also means to trace and mark. If they are the same, there would be really no point to use them in the same time.

So how are they different?

---

By the way, I don't have enough reputation to post a image, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think "produce" in Thomas Heath's translation means to extend, i.e. to make it longer.

Comment: No, I mean the difference between to "draw" and to "describe"